# PHP header not working in foreach

Tags: php, oop, http

Somewhat strange situation here

```
$location = 'Location: http://localhost/pages';
//header($location); exit; works
$response->header($location)->send(); exit; //doesn't work
```

and the `$response` object's class

```
public headers = [];

public function header($string, $replace = true, $code = 200)
{
    $this->headers[] = [
        'string' => $string,
        'replace' => $replace,
        'code' => $code
    ];

    return $this;
}

public function send()
{
    foreach ($this->headers as $header) {
        header($header['string'], $header['replace'], $header['code']);
    }
}
```

The code works fine when using vanilla `header` but it doesn't when using the methods. Am I missing something here?

Comment: try $response->header($location) then $response->send()

Comment: @MikeKor I am chaining them... see `return $this`

Comment: sorry didn't notice it. ok the problem is in this row header($header['string'], $header['replace'], $header['code']).

Comment: @CD001 yeah, didn't provide the constructor as it felt to be redundant here. No errors. Nothing.

Comment: $header values in loop are values of ['string'] then  ['replace'] and ['code'] but you try to access it as if it's an array.

Comment: @MikeKor and where exactly?

Comment: @etilge, in foreach($this->headers as $header) loop 1st iteration $header is value of $headers['string'] 2nd iteration  $header  is value of $headers['replace']. am i wrong?

Comment: Inside the loop, you should use $this->header(...) to call the function?

Comment: @jolmos no, you shouldn't

Comment: Engaged brain an had a bit of a run-through of what's actually happening - I suspect jbafford's answer below is bang on the money... you're not getting any PHP errors because there aren't any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are returning the `Location` header to the browser with a `200` status code.

For a redirection to actually occur, a `3xx` response code should be sent instead (usually, a `302`). A `200` response code simply means "OK, content follows". For a redirection to actually take place, a 3xx response code must be given.

Your code is ultimately calling

```
header('Location: http://localhost/pages', true, 200);
```

which isn't going to result in the browser redirecting you to the desired location.

PHP itself special-cases calls to `header('Location: ...')` and unless otherwise specified, uses a `302` instead of leaving the response code unchanged. You may want to adjust your code to do the same to keep the same behavior as PHP.

Also, important to note that, while every HTTP response only has one response code, `header()` allows you to set the response code each time you call it.

Thus, if you use your code like this:

```
$response
    ->header("Location: http://localhost/pages", true, 302)
    ->header("SomeOtherheader: value")
    ->send()
;
```

the `302` you *intended* to send will get replaced with the `200` that gets set in the next call to `header()`.

Instead, what you should do is either separate the concept of setting the status code from actually setting the header content, e.g.:

```
$response
    ->header("Location: http://localhost/pages"))
    ->header("SomeOtherheader: value")
    ->responseCode(302)
    ->send()
;
```

or instead do what `header()` does and treat an unspecified response code as meaning, don't change the what's already been set:

```
public function header($string, $replace = true, $code = false) { ... }
```

`false` (or `0`) passed on to PHP's `header()` will indicate that.

Comment: Uhm, no... IMHO, you can pass any code with any header.

Comment: @etilge You *can*, but not if you want the browser to actually redirect, though.

Comment: still, I am using just header and passing arguments into. No magic there.

Comment: No magic, but you're ultimately calling `header('Location: http://localhost/pages', true, 200)`, which is *not* going to result in a redirection.